# How to efficiently handle user input specifications in python

Tags: python

Say I have an object that has 2 attributes: velocity and position. When updating these attributes I would like to be able to pass an argument to the function that will continuously print these attributes, something like:

```
def function(shouldPrint=None):
    # Do some stuff, update attributes

    if shouldPrint == 'position':
        print(object.position)

    if shouldPrint == 'velocity':
        print(object.velocity)
```

Is there a way to do this using dictionaries? The two example case is simple but if I have more attributes that I would like to log the code quickly gets messy. Is there any better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def function(shouldPrint=None):
   
    if shouldPrint is not None and hasattr(obj, shouldPrint):
        print(getattr(obj, shouldPrint))
```

You can use `hasattr` and `getattr` for this. If `shouldPrint` is an existing attribute, print the object's corresponding value.

Comment: Rather than usin `obj.__dict__()`, I usually prefer using `hasattr()` and `getattr()`, respectively, for this kind of thing.

Comment: @GreenCloakGuy good idea, thanks.